# Problem when reloading page using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, routes, react-router-dom

I managed to make a private route and navigate to different pages using `react-router-dom`. How ever, when I navigate to a page and reload it, it first goes to `/login` for half a second and the reloads the page correctly. How can I prevent this unwanted behavior and improve my routing?

Here are my routes:

```
    <Router>
      <Route
        path="/"
        component={() =>
          !auth ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <Redirect to={path} />
        }
      />
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={RedirectPage} />
    </Router>
```

This is the full component:

```
import {
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Button } from "@material-ui/core/";
import Login from "./Login";
import { useContext,useState } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../App";
import { signOut } from "../Storage/Auth";

const Routes = () => {
  const { auth, setAuth, logging } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [path,setPath] = useState("/home")
  const handleSignOut = () => {
    signOut(setAuth);
    console.log("Auth", auth);
  };

  const Home = () => {
    console.log("Home");
    return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <Link to="/">
          <Button onClick={handleSignOut}> Log Out</Button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/dashboard">
          <Button> Dash</Button>
        </Link>
      </Container>
    );
  };

  const Dashboard = () => {
    setPath("/dashboard")
    console.log("Dash");
    return (
      <Container>
        <Link to="/home">
          <Button> HOME</Button>
        </Link>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      </Container>
    );
  };

  const RedirectPage = () => {
    if (!logging) {
      return <div></div>;
    } else {
      return <Login />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Route
        path="/"
        component={() =>
          !auth ? <Redirect to="/login" /> : <Redirect to={path} />
        }
      />
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={RedirectPage} />
    </Router>
  );
};

export { Routes };
```

This is my `Login` component.

```
import { useState, useContext } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  Container,
  Typography,
  Box,
  TextField,
} from "@material-ui/core/";
import { useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import { signIn } from "../Storage/Auth";
import { UserContext } from "../App";

const Login = () => {
  const [mail, setMail] = useState<string>("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>("");
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  const handleSignIn = async (m: string, p: string) => {
    await signIn(m, p).then((e) => {
      console.log("USERID", e, user);
      setUser(e);
    });
  };

  const history = useHistory();
  const handleEnter = () => {
    history.push("/home");
  };

  const handleOnKey = (e: any) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleSignIn(mail, password);
      handleEnter();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Card className="Card" raised={true}>
      <Container className="Input">
        <Typography className="Sign-in" paragraph={true} variant="inherit">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <Box
          className="Box"
          borderColor="error.main"
          border={2}
          borderRadius="borderRadius"
        >
          <Container>
            <TextField
              fullWidth={true}
              placeholder=" email"
              value={mail}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setMail(e.target.value);
              }}
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                handleOnKey(e);
              }}
            />
          </Container>
        </Box>
      </Container>
      <Container className="Input">
        <Box
          className="Box"
          borderColor="error.main"
          borderRadius="borderRadius"
          border={2}
        >
          <Container>
            <TextField
              fullWidth={true}
              placeholder=" password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setPassword(e.target.value);
              }}
              type="password"
              onKeyDown={(e) => {
                handleOnKey(e);
              }}
            />
          </Container>
        </Box>
        <h1> </h1>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            handleSignIn(mail, password);
          }}
          fullWidth={true}
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
          type="submit"
        >
          Sign In{" "}
        </Button>
        <h1> </h1>
        <Box className="Sign-in">
            <Button size="small"> Register </Button>
        </Box>
        <h1> </h1>
      </Container>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

This is the `App` component:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes } from "./Routing/Routes";
import "./App.css";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core/";
import initFirebase from "./Storage/Secret";
import { useState, createContext } from "react";
import { onAuthChange } from "./Storage/Auth";

export const UserContext = createContext<any>(null);
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<string | null>("");
  const [logging, setLogging] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    initFirebase();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthChange(setAuth,setLogging);
  }, [auth]);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser, auth,setAuth,logging }}>
      <div className="App">
        <Container>
          <Routes />
        </Container>
      </div>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also, here is the `auth` logic:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";

const auth = () => firebase.auth();

const signIn = async (email, password) => {
  await auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      var user = userCredential.user;
      console.log("USER", user);
      return user.uid;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      alert(errorCode, errorMessage);
      return null;
    });
};

const onAuthChange = (setState, setLoading) => {
  auth().onAuthStateChanged((u) => {
    if (!u) {
      console.log(u);
      setLoading(true);
    } else {
      setState(u);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  });
};

const signOut = (setState) => {
    auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(function () {
      console.log("LOGGED OUT");
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("ERROR LOGGING OUT");
    });
  setState(null);
};
export { signIn, signOut, onAuthChange }
```

Finally, the full code is in https://gitlab.com/programandoconro/adminkanjicreator

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you share your private route component so we can see what it does while resolving the auth status, and also the code where you use a private route? I suspect you *don't* actually have a `PrivateRoute` component implemented though judging by your code snippet. Can you also include your `UserContext` code? If you need help implementing an auth flow, check the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) for a auth workflow example.

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the question and also added this link to the full repo https://gitlab.com/programandoconro/adminkanjicreator

Comment: What are the normal values for the `auth` state? You can start with initial state that isn't the same as your "authenticated" or "unauthenticated" state and wait for the value to ***not*** be equal to the initial state.

Comment: @DrewReese I add the auth logic. Thank you for your suggestion. I will experiment on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue. Now the reload works perfectly and the security was implemented as excepted. This is my final `Router`:

```
<Router>
      <Route
        path="/"
        render={() =>
          logging ? <Redirect to={"/login"} /> : <Redirect to={path} />
        }
      />
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => auth && <Home />} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={() => auth && <Dashboard />} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
</Router>
```

This is how the component looks like now.

```
import {
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Button } from "@material-ui/core/";
import Login from "./Login";
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../App";
import { signOut } from "../Storage/Auth";

const Routes = () => {
  const { auth, setAuth, logging } = useContext(UserContext);
  const handleSignOut = () => {
    signOut(setAuth);
    console.log("Auth", auth);
  };
  const pathname = window.location.pathname;
  const [path, setPath] = useState(pathname);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(path);
    path === "/login" && setPath("/");
    path !== "/" && path !== "/dashboard" && setPath("/");
  }, [auth]);

  const Home = () => {
    console.log("Home");
    return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <Link to="/">
          <Button onClick={handleSignOut}> Log Out</Button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/dashboard">
          <Button> Dash</Button>
        </Link>
      </Container>
    );
  };

  const Dashboard = () => {
    console.log("Dash");
    return (
      <Container>
        <Link to="/">
          <Button> HOME</Button>
        </Link>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      </Container>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Route
        path="/"
        render={() =>
          logging ? <Redirect to={"/login"} /> : <Redirect to={path} />
        }
      />
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => auth && <Home />} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" render={() => auth && <Dashboard />} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Router>
  );
};

export { Routes };
```

Thanks @Richard and @Drew for their kind support.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing the auth check earlier. So something like this so that the routes themselves only get rendered if there is something in auth. I think your example is also missing the Switch statement which often helps.

```js
<Router>
    {!auth ? (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={RedirectPage} />
        </Switch>
    ) : (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
    )}
</Router>
```

Comment: I am experimenting with your suggestion to make it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you will want some sort of "loading" or "indeterminant" state to represent neither authenticated nor unauthenticated. You can use this third "state" to hold the UI before committing to rendering one way or the other on anything based upon authentication.

Since your `auth` logic resolves to a boolean `true`|`false`.

```
const onAuthChange = (setState, setLoading) => {
  auth().onAuthStateChanged((u) => {
    if (!u) {
      console.log(u);
      setLoading(true);
    } else {
      setState(u);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  });
};
```

You can use the fact that the initial `auth` state is neither of these. I suggest using `null`.

```
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<string | null>(null);
```

When rendering the `Route` utilizing the `auth` state you can augment the logic to return early before deciding to redirect.

```
<Route
  path="/"
  render={() => {
    if (auth === null) return null;
    return <Redirect to={auth ? path : "/login" />;
  }}
/>
```

Note here that I've also switched over to the `render` prop, the `component` prop is intended for attaching actual React components. These are treated a little differently. You can read about the route render method differences [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods).

The full router example:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route path="/login" component={RedirectPage} />
    <Route
      path="/"
      render={() => {
        if (auth === null) return null;
        return <Redirect to={auth ? path : "/login" />;
      }}
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Note here that I've also included the `Switch` component and reordered the routes so the more specific paths are listed before less specific paths. This allows you to remove the unnecessary `exact` prop from all the routes since the `Switch` renders routes exclusively (*versus inclusively as the `Router` does*).